# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar arreglo multidimensional en Laravel, agrupando los registros por el valor de un campo?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

En estos momentos lo que quiero hacer es una aplicación de ventas.
Actualmente quiero que mi sistema después de lanzar la consulta que es un arreglo multidimensional pueda tener solo los valores agrupados por el valor de una columna product_group.

la consulta que me llega es la siguiente.

```
[Array : Item
     [ 0 = Item
          [
               id=1,
               codigo=191718,
               name="Vela # 1",
               product_group="VELON # 1",
               color="AMARILLO",
               cuantity=10,
               discount=0,
               p_sale=880,
               total=8800,
          ]
     ]
     [ 1 = Item
          [
               id=1,
               codigo=191718,
               name="Vela # 1",
               product_group="VELON # 1",
               color="BLANCO",
               cuantity=10,
               discount=0,
               p_sale=880,
               total=8800,
          ]
     ]
     [ 2 = Item
          [
               id=1,
               codigo=191788,
               name="Vela # 2",
               product_group="VELON # 2",
               color="BLANCO",
               cuantity=10,
               discount=0,
               p_sale=1880,
               total=8800,
          ]
     ]
]
```

La consulta de mi controlador es:

```
$detail=DB::table('sale_details as sd')
            ->join('products as prod','sd.product_id','=','prod.id')
            ->select('prod.name','prod.codigo', 'prod.product_group','sd.id','sd.cuantity','sd.color','sd.p_sale','sd.discount')
            ->where('sd.sale_id','=',$id)
            ->get();

$detail->groupBy('product_group');
```

Lo que me gustaría que me mostrara la aplicación seria esto:

[image: Captura de ejemplo de vista]

En este ejemplo de vista esta como deseo mostrar los elementos después de agruparlos.

Lo he intentado en varias formas con while, for y foreach pero no llego al resultado deseado, actualmente todo la aplicación funciona pero solo esta parte de la vista no la he podido lograr, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Dejo un ejemplo sencillo, no es muy elegante y es sin utilizar las directivas del motor de plantillas de laravel pero te servirá para ver como se crea la tabla:

```
/*Array de ejemplo*/
$arr = array( 0 => ['id'=>1,
                    'codigo'=>191718,
                    'name'=>"Vela # 1",
                    'product_group'=>"VELON # 1",
                    'color'=>"AMARILLO",
                    'cuantity'=>10,
                    'discount'=>0,
                    'p_sale'=>880,
                    'total'=>8800],

              1 => ['id'=>1,
                    'codigo'=>191718,
                    'name'=>"Vela # 1",
                    'product_group'=>"VELON # 1",
                    'color'=>"BLANCO",
                    'cuantity'=>10,
                    'discount'=>0,
                    'p_sale'=>880,
                    'total'=>8800,],

              2 => ['id'=>1,
                    'codigo'=>191788,
                    'name'=>"Vela # 2",
                    'product_group'=>"VELON # 2",
                    'color'=>"BLANCO",
                    'cuantity'=>10,
                    'discount'=>0,
                    'p_sale'=>1880,
                    'total'=>8800,] 
            );  

/*Imprimir la tabla*/
echo "<table border='1'>
        <thead>";
            foreach (array_keys($arr[0]) as $v) {
                echo "<td>{$v}</td>";
            }
  echo "</thead>
        <tbody>";
            foreach ($arr as $v) { 
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($v as $value) { echo "<td>{$value}</td>"; }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
  echo "</tbody>
      </table>";
```

Si necesitas algo mas elaborado me avisas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, voy a probarlo y cualquier cosa yo escribo, y también comparto la solución con blade.